# How can I create my own fork of Creative Commons license for a book - educational use

Tags: license-recommendation, multi-licensing

How can I create my own educational license for my scholar books?

I'm thinking in a fork of CC BY-SA-NC + educational use. What should I have in mind before write the license?

These is our draft for the human-readable summary of the license:

> You are free to:
>
> - Share – copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
> - Adapt – remix, transform, and build upon the material
>
> The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms.
> Under the following terms:
>
> - Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
> - NonCommercial —You may not use the material for commercial purposes.
> - ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.
> - EducationCommunity — May be used solely for purposes directly related to learning, teaching, training, research or development in a qualified educational institution and shall not be used for commercial, professional or any other for-profit purposes.​ https://terlicense.wordpress.com/ter-full/#EC
>
> No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

Notices:

- When the Licensor is an intergovernmental organization or educational institution, disputes will be resolved by mediation and arbitration unless otherwise agreed.
- You do not have to comply with the license for elements of the material in the public domain or where your use is permitted by an applicable exception or limitation. No warranties are given.
- The license may not give you all of the permissions necessary for your intended use. For example, other rights such as publicity, privacy,
  or moral rights may limit how you use the material.

**Do I have to take care of something else?**

> The full license is https://terlicense.wordpress.com/

Comment: I voted this question as off-topic. The license you want is not open source according to the [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/osd), because you want it to discriminate based on group affiliation and on field of endeavor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about crafting a license that is fundamentally not open source.

Comment: Questions asking the community to *build* a license are off-topic because they don't ask the community to recommend a license already available. If you would like the community to recommend you a license that meets your criteria, please read [How do I ask for a license recommendation?](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/463/how-do-i-ask-for-a-license-recommendation) Thanks :)

Comment: Don't do it. There are already too many licenses to choose from. Select e.g. a CC one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I suggest you think about.

- How do you define educational use? This can be tricky, almost everything with content can claim that content is somehow educational. An advertisement could claim it educates the public on some product.

  Accreditation as an educational institution may be overly limiting and leave out educational websites that host tutorials and other such things. Furthermore some countries may not have effective accrediting bodies or none at all.
- Non-free and non-open. Your license won't be OSI approved, because even if the OSI would consider your license (which is unlikely unless it proves wildely popular) it will not approve it for the same reasons CC BY-SA-NC is not approved.

Furthermore, [How can a "crayon" license be a problem?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem) list additional problems with a home-made license, including

- License proliferation. Yet another license that is incompatible with other resources. Your license will not be compatible with any free license, nor with CC BY-SA-NC as it imposes additional restrictions rather than additional freedoms.
- If you're not a copyright lawyer, writing your own license that means what you want it to mean can be problematic.

See also all points in the related question

Comment: **Educational use:** May be used solely for purposes directly related to learning, teaching, training, research or development in a qualified educational institution.

**License proliferation:** that is the reason we want to create a fork of Creative Commons, because we just want to create an additional restriction. Just for educational purpose.

**Sorry, what does it mean CC NA**

**If you're not a copyright lawyer,**  We have a lawyer, but i think if we do a fork of Creative Commons, 90 % of the work is done and it´s great.

Comment: I'm working with Colomet on this project and i have a couple of questions for you. Could you explain better the second point? The one about license proliferation and incompatibility? Our intention is to give our material under the cc by-sa-nc license only for educational purpose. If, for example, a private company wants to use it, we want to apply the normal copyright law. Do you know maybe if there's a similar license we could use instead of writing a new one? Can we use CCPlus protocol to add that limitation? Thank you!

Comment: If you got a lawyer, then why do you ask here? You should be discussing this with them.

Comment: @Colomet how direct does a relation need to be to be considered "directly related"? When is an educational institution "qualified"?

Comment: EducationCommunity: https://terlicense.wordpress.com/ter-full/#EC