# Own license creation

Tags: license

For instance, in Github, can we declare our own license (in LICENSE.txt): "make any use only if you declare the author", or must we choose known ones like GPL3, MIT, etc

Comment: Welcome to OS.SE!  You should probably read our question on [GitHub (and other) software without explicit licences](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1720/458), to see what the implications of not choosing a licence are, and our question on [crayon licences](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1445/458), to see what the implications of writing your own licence are.  If those two leave you with any unanswered questions, please edit this question to be clearer about what you still want to know; otherwise, please let us know, so we can close this as a duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the conditions on [GitHub](https://github.com/features) might forbid you doing what you want (unless you pay them). See of course also [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Second, you need to pay a lawyer to write your own license. AFAIK, the [CECILL](http://cecill.info/) license required more than a full time year of work to several lawyers. Law is as difficult as programming (and perhaps even more).

Then, if you invent your license, you'll need to negotiate and convince organizations like [FSF](https://fsf.org/), [OpenSource initiative](https://opensource.org/), [APRIL](https://april.org/), [AFUL](https://aful.org/en) to label your license as open source and compatible with existing ones....

### In practice, if you invent your license, nobody will use your software

(in a professional setting). In many corporations, it is managers and lawyers who dictate what open source licenses developer can use (even to link an existing open source library).

Please read also [this paper](https://www.nber.org/papers/w7600) on the simple economics of open source.

So make us a favor: don't publish your software with your own license. You'll avoid losing your and perhaps our time.

Don't forget a known fact: even if you develop [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) or [open source](https://www.nber.org/papers/w7600) one, you'll have very hard time in attracting users to it. Most code on github is probably almost never used.

<sup>I speak of personal experience, being paid to write free software. The most difficult issue is to find real users</sup>.

PS. Since you live in France, consider joining AFUL or APRIL -I am member of both- and look into [Systematic GTLL](https://systematic-paris-region.org/fr/groupe-thematique-logiciel-libre/). Read J.Tirole's book [*Économie du Bien Commun*](https://www.puf.com/content/%C3%89conomie_du_bien_commun) (it has a long chapter dedicated to open source software), look online into [X.Leroy talks](https://xavierleroy.org/) at [Collège de France](https://www.college-de-france.fr/site/college/index.htm), [Roberto DiCosmo](https://www.dicosmo.org/) website, the [Software Heritage](https://www.softwareheritage.org/) initiative, follow [Séminaire Code Source](https://codesource.hypotheses.org/), and see [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/). If you want to, please send me an email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` mentioning the URL of your question.

Comment: "Law is as difficult as programming (and perhaps even more)." -- Discovering a runtime error in your license terms is certainly much worse, since it takes many thousands of dollars to get an execution environment first. `:)`

Comment: Some bugs costed billions of dollars.