# Are 2 and 3-clause-BSD licenses' texts in the public domain?

Tags: bsd

I've been reading about BSD Lisenses on Wikipedia recently and [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) said that 4 and 3-clause BSD Licenses' texts are in the public domain. But there weren't any links that would prove this apart from the fact that they have Public Domain as their publisher in the article. So, is that really true?
Also, 2-clause BSD license doesn't even have Public Domain as it's publisher. Is 2-clause BSD license's text in the Public Domain?

Comment: While the question itself is perhaps interesting, perhaps a more important question is "why is this important to you?" If you're considering making your own license based on one of the BSD licenses, [please don't do that](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem).

Comment: @PhilipKendall I agree, that creating your own license is a very bad idea. I've asked this question because I didn't find anything on the Internet which would explain why those licenses' texts are considered to be in the public domain even though there isn't (as far as I'm aware) a copyright waiver for BSD Licenses signed by the Regents of the University of California.